# Sql Server 2008 R2 - Parallel Data Warehouse

Tags: sql-server, data-warehouse

Just a question led by pure curiosity:

Are there any implementations of large data warehouses based on SQL Server 2008 R2? Any news about real life performance of the DatAllegro technology?

Regards,
Adam

Answer (score 3):

There are some case studies around.

- [One](http://sqlcat.com/whitepapers/archive/2010/08/23/analysis-services-rolap-for-sql-server-data-warehouses.aspx)
- [Two - Microsoft themselves](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg486866.aspx)
- [Google](http://www.google.co.uk/#sclient=psy&hl=en&safe=active&q=sql+server+2008+r2+analysis+services+case+studies&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=19bff151c0ba26e)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can read about the implementations of Microsoft Analytics Platform System (which runs the Parallel Data Warehouse workload) at the [Royal Bank of Scotland](https://customers.microsoft.com/Pages/CustomerStory.aspx?recid=14155) and [Hy-Vee](https://customers.microsoft.com/Pages/CustomerStory.aspx?recid=13326).

For more details on APS, visit http://aka.ms/pdw